# Another database for login in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to add roles to my website in asp.net mvc 3 so that only an specific role can look at certain controllers.

I read the music store tutorial, and went to the asp .net web administration tool and read that I can customize my provider in the provider tab.

I have in a table called Client from my database and it has columns "Username" "Password" etc.
I want to check the login info in these tables.

I went to the provider tab and I can only see AspNetSqlProvider I cannot see a way to add my database there or anything...(the database is already in my project)

How can I configure this. I've search online but haven't found how. Could anyone point me in the direction to do this?

Comment: implement a custom membership provider.

Comment: BTW, "ASP.NET" is one word - no space.

Comment: it doesnt seem like you have needs that the default membership provider can't handle.  research using that before building your own.  even basic things like storing passwords in a database are non-trivial to implement correctly/securely.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft developed a much simpler membership provider called [SimpleMembership](http://blog.osbornm.com/archive/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages.aspx), that allows you to very easily use an existing database and specify where your usernames/passwords are stored. It was originally introduced for use with the ASP.NET WebPages framework, in WebMatrix, but there already exists a NuGet package that allows you to use it with ASP.NET MVC:

```
webSecurityService.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
    connectionStringName: "Default", 
    userTableName: "Users", 
    userIdColumn: "ID", 
    userNameColumn: "Username", 
    autoCreateTables: true);
```

[SimpleMembership.Mvc3 NuGet Package](http://anderly.com/2011/01/18/simplemembership-mvc3-nuget-package/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a custom membership provider that knows how to check your custom database schema.  Here is a [video](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider) that might get you started.  There are heaps of resources online too now that you know the correct terminology to search for ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Universal Membership Provider](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) Works with SQL Express, Compact, and Azure. Just give it a connection string to your membership DB.